# How to extract multiple integers from a single array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, function

Would somebody here please show me the way to modify the regexp below so that I could then with it get multiple integers per array item? I can detect one integer like in the top-most str below using \d+. However, the function will error out with the other two examples, below it, `str = "7yes9 Sir2"`, etc. Thank you.

```
//str = "10 2One Number*1*";
//output -> [10, 2One, Number*1*] -> [10 + 2 + 1] -> 13

var str = "7Yes9 Sir2";  
//output -> NaN

//var str = "8pop2 1";
//output -> NaN

function NumberAddition(str) {  
  input = str.split(" ");  
  var finalAddUp = 0;  
  var finalArr = [];  

  for(var i = 0; i<=input.length-1; i++) {  
    var currentItem = input[i];  
    var regexp = /(\d+)/g;  
    finalArr.push(Number(currentItem.match(regexp)));  
    var itemToBeCounted = +finalArr[i];  
    finalAddUp += itemToBeCounted;  
  }  
  return finalAddUp;  
}  

console.log(NumberAddition(str));
```

Comment: It fails because the operation `Number` is not allowed on the [array that `match` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and you (clearly!) have more than 1 match. Reconsider your approach.

Comment: I just learned RegExp yesterday. This is for a coding challenge that is being used for learning purposes. I don't know how to reconsider my approach. Again: can you help me? I thought I'd stated I don't know how to find more than one match, regardless. Thanks.

Comment: But you *are* finding more than one match -- that's why you get an error! Try `console.log(currentItem.match(regexp));` on your input. The reason you have to reconsider your approach is because you are already assuming you get 1 match inside the loop.

Comment: Also, and just on the aside as I don't really doubt you about match not allowing Number, I wanted to add that the first array example does indeed work despite that. And it also includes the usage of Number: ie.,
//str = "10 2One Number*1*";
//output -> [10, 2One, Number*1*] -> [10 + 2 + 1] -> 13

Comment: Can I ask why Number is allowed there, but not in the other examples? Just curious, because I don't get this, and you seem to understand far better.

Comment: Also, if not there, where else in your opinion would be a good place to convert the array to Int so I may add the values within?

Comment: One last hint then: `match` returns an *array*. (Please look it up.) An array consisting of a single element, `[10]`, can be converted into a number. More than one -- `[7,9]` cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sth. like

**HTML**

```
<span id="res"></span>
```

**JS**

```
var str = "7Yes9 Sir2";  
var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
var res=0;

for (var i=0; i< matches.length; i++) {
    res += parseInt(matches[i],0);
}

$('#res').html(res);
```

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2zKM/)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Sorry, but unfortunately the website in question only allows JavaScript to be implemented in the solving of the task at hand. It's too bad.

Comment: you mean because of jQuery? Simply do `document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = res;` instead of the jQuery call.